# Bluetooth bonding failing only on LG G5

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an app that connects to a custom Bluetooth component. As we all know, Bluetooth on Android is a nightmare.

Connecting, pairing and bonding works well for all Samsung devices (S5, S6, S7, S8) but fails on LG G5 running Android 6.

The problem is with a specific device. 
It goes to bond state BOND_BONDING bonding and I see this log entry:

```
****** ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED - BOND STATE 11
```

But it never goes to BOND_BONDED. Instead I get BOND_NONE after some time.

```
****** ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED - BOND STATE 10
```

I don't think it's worth sharing the whole code, since this is a problem with a specific version, hence the code is correct. I am looking for suggestions or ideas to workaround this.

```
    // Handles various events fired by the BluetoothService.
    private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case BluetoothService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE://Received data from the device
                    // Doing stuff
                    break;
                case BluetoothService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED:
                    // Doing more stuff
                    break;

                case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED:
                    // Doing amazing stuff
                    break;
                case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED:
                    Integer bondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, 0);
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "****** ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED - BOND STATE " + bondState.toString());

                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

For reference
BOND_NONE is 10. 
BOND_BONDING is 11.
BOND_BONDED is 12.

https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html

Thanks!

Comment: First thoughts are this is a user interaction bluetooth pairing that grandparents won't be able to do.  Then I look down and yep only user can enter the passkey is answer.  You need to code for that interactive pairing.  Also "Only on a LG G5"  Never think like this.  Phone.tostring() != "LG G5"  that will eventually fail on some other manufactures phone.

Answer (score 3):

Please check for `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT`

if `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT` as 1  it denotes only user can enter the `passkey`.But programmatically we can set the passkey using private method named `setpasskey`.

Please use below code :

```
if(type == 1) {
    int pin = Integer.parseInt(devicePin);
    try {
        device.getClass().getMethod("setPasskey", int.class)
                .invoke(device, pin);
        abortBroadcast();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

    }
}
```